# Grails - Editable fields when Creating and Non-editable when Editing

Tags: grails, edit

I'm using Grails 2.3.x

Imagine the domain class: Book (String Author, String Title)

1. When I'm creating a book I need the **Author** field and the **Title** field editable.
2. When I'm editing a book I need the **Author** field **NON**-editable and the **Title** field editable

I know that there is a Domain Constraint (editable: false), but that doesn't work with the second case. It only adds this tag to the readonly="readonly"

I also tried this: [How to conditionally disable a form input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14841302/how-to-conditionally-disable-a-form-input-field)
But it seems that: "${mode == 'edit'}" is always false.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That link you provided assumes that a variable flag called `mode` will be passed into the view to determine whether you are editing or not. To do this, you will need to pass `mode` into the view from your controller like this:

```
def edit(Long id) {
    [bookInstance: new Book(), mode: 'edit']
}
```

That will force the `${mode == 'edit'}` portion to be true.

Comment: Thanks again grantmc, I will try ASAP the both of your answers